# Conditional expectation and expected value

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, conditional-expectation

Given the joint distribution $f(x,y) =  {x \choose y} (\frac{1}{2})^x \frac{x}{20}$ where $y=0,1,2 \cdots x$ and $x=2,3,4,5,6$.
Find $E(y\mid x)$ and $E(y)$

Wondering if I am missing something.

Using Binomial identity and direct definition of $f(x)$ (the limit was from the plot I made):

$f(x) =  (\frac{1}{2})^x \frac{x}{20}  \sum_{y=0}^x   {x \choose y}  =(\frac{1}{2})^x \frac{x}{20}  2^{x} = \frac{x}{20} $

Use $f(x)$ to compute $f(y\mid x)$, given that the joint distribution is given:

So that $f(y\mid x) = \frac{f(x,y)} {f(x)} = \frac{ {x \choose y} (\frac{1}{2})^x \frac{x}{20}}{ \frac{x}{20}} = {x \choose y} 2^{-x} $

$E(y \mid x) = \sum_{y=0}^{x} y f(y\mid x) = 2^{-x}  \sum_{y=0}^{x} {x \choose y} y   $

Then: Using the identity : $  \sum_{y=0}^{x} {x \choose y} y  = x 2^{x-1}  $

$E(y \mid x) = \sum_{y=0}^{x} y f(y\mid x) = 2^{-x}  \sum_{y=0}^{x} {x \choose y} y  = x (2^{-x} \cdot 2^{x-1}) = \frac{x}{2} $

Does this makes sense?

How does $E(y)$ follows, I guess $E(y) = E(E(y \mid x))$

$E(y) = E(E(y \mid x))$

$E(y) = E(E(y \mid x)) = \sum_{x=2}^6 \frac{x}{20} (2^{-x} \sum_{y=0}^{x} {x \choose y} y) =  \frac{1}{40}\sum_{x=2}^6 x^2  $

Comment: Why does the summation start at $y=2$? You need to sum over all values of $y$ which is $0$ to $x$.

Comment: @PedroAmaral x starts at 2, I guess. And from the plot of the regions for x and y, I arrived at 2. Perhaps.

Comment: You are right that $x$ starts at 2 but $y$ starts at $0$ according to your definition. Also you can check that your $f(x)$ is not a probability since summing over all the values of $x$ (2,3,4,5,6) doesn't give you $1$. Try making the sum starting at $0$ and you'll see how much simpler everything becomes.

Comment: you are perhaps right. I mixed up the regions a little bit. Let me try your suggestion, Thanks

Comment: @snoopy Note: $\displaystyle\sum_{y=0}^x y\dbinom xy = x~2^{x-1}$

Comment: Also $\displaystyle\mathsf E(Y) = \sum_{x=\mathbf 2}^6 \dfrac x{20} 2^{-x}~\sum_{y=0}^x y\dbinom xy$

Comment: @GrahamKemp Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The easiest  way to proceed is to observe that your joint pmf is

$$p(x,y)=p(y|x)p(x)=\binom{x}{y}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^x\times\frac{x}{20}$$

Thus $(Y|X=x)\sim Bin\left(x;\frac{1}{2}\right)$

And X is a discrete rv with support $x=\{2,3,4,5,6\}$ and pmf

$$p(X=x)=x/20$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]=x/2$$

And

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]]= \mathbb{E}[X/2]= \frac{1}{2 }\mathbb{E}[X]
 = \frac{1}{2 }\times\frac{9}{2}=\frac{9}{4}$$